# Hyper V - can't connect to virtual machines via the console

Tags: windows-server-2008, hyper-v

I have Hyper-V added

I recently attempted to add a new virtual machine to my Hyper V server but realised there was not enough memory on that server to cope with another machine. I reduced the memory allocated to three other machines and tried again.

After adding the machine, with no operating system yet, I suddenly cannot access any other machines from the Hyper V console.

I double click the machines in the list, or select them and click "Connect" - there is a slight flicker and nothing else happens?

I have since removed the partially created machine.  Restarted the server (a couple of times actually). I've checked the event logs...nothing.

I can start any of the virtual machines and connect to them remotely once they are running but I cannot connect to them, on the host, via the Hyper V console.

What could the problem be? Where should I be looking?

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue where I had to manually reset the hyper v security to get the VMRC to connect.

<strike>I just cant seem to find that website right now.</strike>

I will see if I have a copy of the batch file lying around somewhere.

Ok was a registry fix for this. Save the following to a .reg file to fix the VMRC security issue.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Credssp]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Credssp\PolicyDefaults]

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Credssp\PolicyDefaults\AllowDefaultCredentials]
"Hyper-V"="Microsoft Virtual Console Service/*"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Credssp\PolicyDefaults\AllowDefaultCredentialsDomain]
"Hyper-V"="Microsoft Virtual Console Service/*"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Credssp\PolicyDefaults\AllowFreshCredentials]
"Hyper-V"="Microsoft Virtual Console Service/*"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Credssp\PolicyDefaults\AllowFreshCredentialsDomain]
"Hyper-V"="Microsoft Virtual Console Service/*"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Credssp\PolicyDefaults\AllowFreshCredentialsWhenNTLMOnly]
"Hyper-V"="Microsoft Virtual Console Service/*"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Credssp\PolicyDefaults\AllowFreshCredentialsWhenNTLMOnlyDomain]
"Hyper-V"="Microsoft Virtual Console Service/*"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Credssp\PolicyDefaults\AllowSavedCredentials]
"Hyper-V"="Microsoft Virtual Console Service/*"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Credssp\PolicyDefaults\AllowSavedCredentialsDomain]
"Hyper-V"="Microsoft Virtual Console Service/*"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa\Credssp\PolicyDefaults\AllowSavedCredentialsWhenNTLMOnly]
"Hyper-V"="Microsoft Virtual Console Service/*"
```

Comment: Hmmm - hasn't helped but +1 for so much effort. It may well help someone else too.

Comment: Sorry has not helped your situation. You maybe alone here trying to resolve it. I wish I could duplicate it but I cannot

Answer (score 0):

The answer has turned out to be a bit scary.

I had placed a web cam on that server as I was toying with the idea of monitoring the server room via it...long story. Anyway, I removed that web cam software and HyperV Manager is working again.